# How do I "activate" a radio button that hasn't load yet?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, radio-group

How do I "active" a radio button that hasn't been load yet?

It's like .live() but only for radio button.

Comment: You want to automatically check radio buttons as they are inserted into the document, right?

Comment: it sould like you have to do that server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with jQuery unless you have to. If you're adding an element to the page or if it's an element that's meant to be checked when the page first loads, just set the value right in the HTML (or whatever server-side language creates HTML output):

```
<input type="radio" name="myGroup" value="My Value" checked /> My Value
```

If it *IS* being added with jQuery, I assume it's being done with `.html()` or `.append()` or whatever other method; in which case the advice still applies:

```
var radioValue = 'My Value';
var newRadio = '<input type="radio" name="myGroup" value="' + radioValue + '" checked />' + radioValue;

$('#myForm').append(newRadio);
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method ( prior to jQuery 1.6)

```
$('#radioButtonID').prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: What if the radio button is in a button group?

Comment: .attr() effectively replaces .prop() in this use case -- no need to use a pre-1.6 jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('input[name=field]:eq(1)').attr('checked', 'checked');
```